# Colocar logo no topo ao redimensionar página

Tags: html

Estou tentando deixar o logo da empresa acima de todo o conteúdo no momento em que a página é redimensionada, mas sem sucesso.

Chamada do logo:

```html
<a class="logo pull-left" href="index.php"> <img src="assets/images/logo-chipi.jpg" alt="" /> </a>
```

O código que tenho é esse:

Página `layout.css`:

```
#header a.logo>img {
    height:80px;
    -webkit-transition: all .300s;
       -moz-transition: all .300s;
         -o-transition: all .300s;
            transition: all .300s;
}
#header a.logo.logo-responsive>img {
    height:100%; /* used on center - example: page-coming-soon-1.html */
}
```

A o logo está ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O site pode ser visto aqui:
[Site em Desenvolvimento](http://topdeia.com.br/n-chipi/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu utilizaria o width na header a.logo.logo-responsive>img

Assim
header a.logo.logo-responsive>img {
width:90%
}

assim diminuiria um pouco o tamanho do logo fazendo-o caber na sua menu bar

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando media queries? caso esteja, na hora em que o menu virar hamburguer, defina o `<a>` que envolve a imagem do logo com `position: absolute`